# How do I get a 30 minute break while working or doing anything on computers?

Tags: linux, debian, software-rec, health

I am running Debian. Many times I get cramped (or something) for being on the computer for to long. Is there a tool which will tell me after 30-40 minutes to take a break?

I remember seeing something, but I have forgotten what it is called.

Comment: a timer will tell you

Comment: The sister site [*Software Recommendations*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) might be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Maybe... a clock? There's already one on your desktop. Or you can get a watch. Or put a clock on your wall. Or glance at your oven timer. So many possibilities on _how to tell the time_. If you're getting so sucked in that you "forget" to know what the time is and how long you've been sat working, that to me would be something you need to solve on the emotional level.

Comment: I have this on my android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.catfantom.multitimerfree

Comment: Google suggests https://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2007/07/03/prevent-repetitive-strain-injury-rsi-take-a-timed-break-with-standard-gnome-software/

Answer (score 27):

I use [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/) for this; it’s available in Debian as the `workrave` package.

I also noticed [Safe Eyes](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes), available as the `safeeyes` package, but haven’t tried it.

Comment: Workrave is indeed good. However, in Ubuntu 20 it does not start on its own during startup and does not show up on the system tray either.

Answer (score 15):

`xwrits` available in the standard repository is another one.

```
Description: reminds you to take a break from typing
 xwrits helps you prevent repetitive stress injury.
 .
 xwrits is a small reminder program designed to let you know it is time
 to take a break from typing to rest your wrists and prevent any damage
 to your wrists (or at least make them feel better if you've already
 damaged them). Normally works on the honor system, but if you find
 yourself unable to stop typing during your break, it can also lock your
 keyboard.
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Stretchly](https://hovancik.net/stretchly/downloads/) as a breaktime reminder:

> A microbreak for 20 seconds every 10 minutes.
>
> Every 30 minutes, it displays a window containing an idea for a longer 5 minute break.

The description is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly). To install Stretchly, download the .deb package from [here](https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/releases/tag/v0.18.0).

```
wget https://github.com/hovancik/stretchly/releases/download/v0.18.0/stretchly_0.18.0_amd64.deb
gdebi stretchly_0.18.0_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 8):

I use a minimal cron, which displays the time every 30 minutes. It relies on libnotify:

```
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/notify-send "$(date +"Time is %r")"
```

and the crontab statement is:

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/clock.zsh
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the [Pomodoro Timer](http://gnomepomodoro.org/) to keep track of time, as it alerts me when I should take a break and when I should resume working.

It was designed to help structure your work flow based on the [Pomodoro Technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique), and therefore defaults to 25 minutes of work, followed by 5 minutes of break-time. However, it is easily customizable, and you can set the duration according to your own preferences.

It comes with a nice graphical interface as well, and is available as debian package under the name of [gnome-shell-pomodoro](https://packages.debian.org/sid/main/gnome-shell-pomodoro).

Answer (score 0):

[Take a Break](https://launchpad.net/takeabreak) is something that works well. It is for Ubuntu/Debian.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/takeabreak
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install takeabreak
```

There's a similar question in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696620/a-timer-that-automatically-locks-the-screen-to-take-a-break-away-from-the-comput)